# wait for kernel after creating partition with sftdisk on linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-kernel, udev

I am creating a partition with sfdisk under linux. After partition creation I want to create a filesystem.

This fails with mkfs.ext3 not finding the partition:

```
echo ",,L" | sfdisk $DEVICE
mkfs.ext3 $PARTITION
```

But this works:

```
echo ",,L" | sfdisk $DEVICE
sleep 1
mkfs.ext3 $PARTITION
```

I suspect, either the kernel takes some time to update it's internal data structures, or my script gets scheduled again, before udev had a chance to create the device node.

How do I wait exactly until the device node is created? With every constant time, there may be a system under load where this time is not eneugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the low-tech solution, if you know in advance the device name:

```
while [ ! -e /dev/whatever ] ; do 
  sleep .1 # you can sleep for less than a second with coreutils sleep
  # optionally add a counter & timeout
done
```

Comment: polling is not the nicest concept, but so far nobody came up with something better

Answer (score 6):

Later, but better than never. For completeness.

```
udevadm settle --timeout=15 --exit-if-exists=$PARTITION
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) (from inotify-tools) on <strike>the device node.</strike> the `/dev` directory.

Comment: inotifywait faìls when called for non existing file

Comment: @johannes: It will work when called for `/dev`, though.

Comment: what if the file gets created before inotywait starts?

Comment: Check if file exists with `if [[ -e /dev/whatever ]]; then ...; fi` before invoking inotifywait.

Comment: what if the file gets created inbetwen the -e and the invokation of inotifywait?

Comment: If that is a concern - then it gets complicated.  Invoke `inotifywait` with the `--daemon` option writing to a file before your `sfdisk` command.  `inotifywait` will then, in the background, write a CREATE event to a file when the device in `/dev` appears.  You need to then write a `while` loop that spins on reading the file and then breaking out of the `while` when it finds the CREATE event.  Then you kill your `inotifywait` process.  I'm certain this solution isn't optimal.